# Role of Warps in NVIDIA GPU architecture with OpenCL

Tags: cuda, opencl

I'm studying OpenCL concepts as well as the CUDA architecture for a small project, and there is one thing that is unclear to me: the necessity for Warps.

I know a lot of questions have been asked on this subject, however after having read some articles i still don't get the "meaning" of warps.

As far as I understand (speaking for my GPU card which is a Tesla, but i guess this easily translates to other boards):

- A work-item is linked to a CUDA thread, which several of them can be executed by a Streaming Processor (SP). BTW, does a SP treats those WI in parallel?
- Work-items are grouped into Work-groups. Work-groups operate on a Stream Multiprocessor and can not migrate. However, work-items in a work-group can collaborate via shared memory (a.k.a local memory). One or more work-groups may be executed by a Stream MultiProcessor. BTW, does a SM treats those WG in parallel?
- Work-item are executed in parallel inside a work-group. However, synchronization is NOT guaranteed, that's why you need concurrent programming primitives, such as barriers.

As far as I understand, all of this is rather a logical view than a 'physical', hardware perspective.

If all of the above is correct, can you help me on the following. Is that true to say that:

1 - Warps execute 32 threads or work-items simultaneously. Thus, they will 'consume' parts of a work-group. And that's why in the end you need stuff like memory fences to synchronize work-items in work groups.

2 - The Warp scheduler allocates the registers for the 32 threads of warp when it becomes active.

3 - Also, are executed thread in a warp synchronized at all?

Thanks for any input on Warps, and especially why they are necessary in the CUDA architecture.

Comment: There's something wrong with the title. "CUDA architecture with OpenCL" is just... wrong. "NVIDIA GPU architecture with OpenCL" would have been more appropriate IMO.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae downvoting is plain stupid. I'm asking a simple question on warps for something i did not understood. I exposed my understanding of the concepts i managed to understand. Now what? Is the purpose of SO to ask 'beautiful' questions (lol) or gain knowledge from others? Anyway, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best analogon is that a Warp is the vector that be processed in parallel, not unlike an AVX or SSE vector with an Intel CPU. This makes an SM a 32-length vector processor.

Then, to your questions:

1. Yes, all 32 elements will be run in parallel. Note that also a GPU puts hyperthreading to the extreme: a workgroup will consist of multiple Warps, which all are run more-or-less in parallel. You will need memory fences to sychronise that all.
2. Yes, typically all 32 work elements (CUDA: thread) in a Warp will work in parallel. Note that you typically will have multiple regsters per work element.
3. Not guaranteed, AFAIK.

Comment: Threads in one warp are always executed in lockstep, which means there is one instruction counter per warp, and all threads in a warp always execute the same instruction in the same clock cycle, if they execute any at all. Some of the threads in a warp may be masked out, that is, produce no effect on memory accesses and registers. This allows for code branching.

Comment: @void_ptr Executed in lockstep does not necessarily imply that all threads of the warp are executed in the same clock cycle. On some hardware for example, the warp scheduler cannot issue an instruction to the whole warp at once, and will instead repeat that instruction over several clock cycles to subsets of the warp before moving onto the next instruction.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae True, I was trying to keep it simpler for now. It may take up to 32 clock cycles to schedule a warp. The key point was that there's one instruction pointer per warp.

Comment: So, it seems that the answer to 3. is that this _is_ guaranteed. Even if half-warps execute at different cycles etc., the processor behaves as though all warp threads executed at the same time, meaning that they are guaranteed to be completely synchronized for all intents of purposes. IIANM.